# Angular ui ng-repeat + ui-if Problems

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am working on a web application and try to get a list of Accordion Elements by using ng-repeat like this:

```
<div ui-State="myAccordion">
  <div ng-repeat="x in [1, 2, 3]">
    <div ui-set="{'myAccordion': x}">
      <h1>Headline {{x}}</h1>
    </div>
    <div ui-if="myAccordion == x">
      Value {{x}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

sadly the `div` with my value wont show up on click, but if I change my conditional to `ui-if="myAccordion == 1"` it works, but will open everything. So I guess the `ui-if` is not taking my ng-repeat value correctly. Has anyone an idea to fix this? Or do I have to use another Solution?

Comment: As far as i now ui-if was removed at least from latest version angular-ui but since angular 1.1.5 you have ng-if build-in.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i now ui-if was removed at least from latest version angular-ui but since angular 1.1.5 you have ng-if build-in

[Tutorial](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2659-migrating-from-ui-if-to-ng-if-in-angularjs.htm)

[Git](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/issues/29)